# plot_partial_dependence() from scikit-learn incorrectly raises NotFittedError for properly fitted models (e.g. KerasRegressor or LGBMClassifier)

Tags: python, validation, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create partial dependence plots using `sklearn.inspection.plot_partial_dependence` on a model that I successfully built using keras and the keras sklearn wrapper utility (see code block below). The wrapped model successfully builds, it can use the fit method, and after fitting it can use the predict method with expected results. All indications are that it's a valid estimator. However, when I try to run plot_partial_dependence from sklearn.inspection, I get some error text implying that it is is *not* a valid estimator, even though I can demonstrate that it is.

I have edited this to be more easily reproducible by using the sklearn example Boston housing data.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.inspection import plot_partial_dependence, partial_dependence
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

boston = load_boston()
feature_names = boston.feature_names
X = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
y = boston.target
mean = X.describe().transpose()['mean']
std = X.describe().transpose()['std']
X_norm = (X-mean)/std

def build_model_small():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=[len(X.keys())]),
        keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(1)
        ])

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.0005)

    model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mae', 'mse', 'mape'])
    return model


kr = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model_small,verbose=0)
kr.fit(X_norm,y, epochs=100, validation_split = 0.2)
pdp_plot = plot_partial_dependence(kr,X_norm,feature_names)
```

Like I said, if I run `kr.predict(X.head(20))`, I get 20 predictions of `y` values for the first 20 rows of `X`, as one would expect from a valid estimator.

But the error text I get from plot_partial_dependence is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp_ML_tf_sklearn_postproc.py", line 79, in <module>
    pdp_plot = plot_partial_dependence(kr,X,labels[:-1])
  File "/home/mymachine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/inspection/_partial_dependence.py", line 678, in plot_partial_dependence
    for fxs in features)
  File "/home/mymachine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 921, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/mymachine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 759, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/mymachine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 716, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/mymachine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 182, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/home/mymachine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 549, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/home/mymachine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/mymachine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/mymachine/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/inspection/_partial_dependence.py", line 307, in partial_dependence
    "'estimator' must be a fitted regressor or classifier."
ValueError: 'estimator' must be a fitted regressor or classifier.
```

I looked at the source code for plot_partial_dependence, and it had the following to say.
First, in the docstring, it says the first input `estimator` must be...

> ```
>   A fitted estimator object implementing :term:`predict`,
>     :term:`predict_proba`, or :term:`decision_function`.
>     Multioutput-multiclass classifiers are not supported.
> ```

My estimator does in deed implement .predict.

Second, the line called out in the errr traceback calls a checker that checks whether it is a regressor or classifier:

```
if not (is_classifier(estimator) or is_regressor(estimator)):
    raise ValueError(
        "'estimator' must be a fitted regressor or classifier."
    )
```

I looked into the source code of is_regressor(), and it is a one liner like so:

```
return getattr(estimator, "_estimator_type", None) == "regressor"
```

So I tried to sort of hack it by doing `setattr(mp,'_estimator_type','regressor')` and it just said `Attribute Error: can't set attribute`, so that's one cheap workaround that didn't work.

I even tried the even hackier fix and temporarily commented out the offending check in the source of _partial_dependence.py (the if statement I copied above), and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp_ML_tf_sklearn_postproc.py", line 79, in <module>
    pdp_plot = plot_partial_dependence(kr,X,labels[:-1])
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/inspection/_partial_dependence.py", line 678, in plot_partial_dependence
    for fxs in features)
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 921, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 759, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 716, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 182, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 549, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/inspection/_partial_dependence.py", line 317, in partial_dependence
    check_is_fitted(est)
  File "/home/billy/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 967, in check_is_fitted
    raise NotFittedError(msg % {'name': type(estimator).__name__})
sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This KerasRegressor instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Which goes all the way back around to the problem of the sklearn functions not thinking this model is fitted, when it really is. Anyway at this point I decided not to try any more dangerous, hacky fixes of tinkering with the source code.

I also tried passing `kr.fit(X,y,etc...)` directly in as the first argument of plot_partial_dependence. The computer spun up for a few minutes, indicating the fit was in fact running, but then I got the same error once it tried to run the partial dependence plot.

One more rather confusing clue. I tried using the keras/sklearn wrapped pipeline in another sklearn function entirely, to see if it would work with any sklearn utilities at all. This time, I did:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
cv_scores = cross_validate(kr,X_norm,y, cv=4, return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)`
```

and it worked! So I don't think there is something inherently wrong with my use of `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor`.

This may just be a case where what I'm trying to do is an edge case not planned for in the plot_partial_dependence source code specifically and I'm out of luck, but I'm wondering if anyone else has seen issues like this and has a solution or work-around.

I am using sklearn 0.22.1 and Python 3.7.3 (Anaconda) by the way. And to be clear, I have used plot_partial_dependence on sklearn-built models and even pipelines. This problem is only happening with the keras-based model. Many thanks for any input people may have.

Edit:

The previous version of this question involved building a pipeline with StandardScaler() and then the KerasRegressor wrapped object. Since then I discovered it happens even with just the KerasRegressor object, i.e. I have isolated the problem to that, not the pipeline. So as one commenter suggested, I took the pipeline part out of the question to make it simpler and more to the point.

Comment: That's weird (reproduced it). I kindly suggest you edit the question (it's kind of too big right now), and remove the (now unnecessary) pipeline stuff. Perhaps make the example fully reproducible with dummy data would be a good idea here (I tried it with `KerasClassifier` and the iris data - same behavior).

Comment: Looks like a generic bug in scikit-learn now, because I get the same error with a different predictor library (`import lightgbm as lgbm; model = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(**params); model.fit(XTrain, yTrain)`), which (I mean `model`) works correctly with a custom-written PDP function.

Comment: Did the proposed solution (the dummy attribute with an underscore) work for you too? It's a breeze to test:)

Comment: Unless I misunderstand - no, adding `kr.dummy_ = "dummy"` did not fix it for the example code above. I did file a bug report in the sklearn GitHub though, thanks for suggesting that.

Answer (score 4):

The issue arises because non-scikit-learn model objects (such as `LightGBMRegressor` or `LGBMClassifier`) do not contain an attribute ending in an underscore, which `check_is_fitted()` uses as a test if the model is fitted (see [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.validation.check_is_fitted.html)).

So an easy workaround would be to add to your trained model object a dummy attribute with a name ending in an underscore:

```
test_model.dummy_ = "dummy"
```

You can also verify that it works by invoking `check_if_fitted()` yourself:

```
from sklearn.utils import validation

validation.check_is_fitted(estimator=test_model)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a cheap work-around, and it works successfully for this specific case. However it's not a very satisfying answer, nor can I guarantee it would work for all cases, so I'd love to see a better answer if anyone has one that is more general. But I'll post this here in case anyone else needs a work-around to this exact problem.

I simply copied the source code (in my anaconda install, it was in `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/inspection/_partial_dependence.py`) into a file called custom_pdp.py in my project directory, in which commented out the offending parts as I (and where necessary, hard-coded my own stand-in values).

In my code, I then used the import line `import custom_pdp as cpdp` instead of importing it from sklearn, and thereafter called plot_partial_dependence as `cpdp.plot_partial_dependence(...)`

Below are the lines I had to change from that source file. Note that you will need to copy the entire source file, since there are other functions defined in it that are needed, but I only made the following changes shown below. Also, this was done with sklearn 0.22.1 - it might not work for other versions.

First, you have to change the relative import lines at the top like so:

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian
from sklearn.utils import check_array
from sklearn.utils import check_matplotlib_support  # noqa
from sklearn.utils import _safe_indexing
from sklearn.utils import _determine_key_type
from sklearn.utils import _get_column_indices
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
from sklearn.tree._tree import DTYPE
from sklearn.exceptions import NotFittedError
from sklearn.ensemble._gb import BaseGradientBoosting
from sklearn.ensemble._hist_gradient_boosting.gradient_boosting import (
    BaseHistGradientBoosting)
```

(they had previously been relative paths like `from ..utils.extmath import cartesian` etc.)

Then, the only functions that are changed are these:

From `_partial_dependence_brute`:

```
def _partial_dependence_brute(est, grid, features, X, response_method):

    ... (skipping docstring)

    averaged_predictions = []

    # define the prediction_method (predict, predict_proba, decision_function).
    # if is_regressor(est):
    #     prediction_method = est.predict
    # else:
    #     predict_proba = getattr(est, 'predict_proba', None)
    #     decision_function = getattr(est, 'decision_function', None)
    #     if response_method == 'auto':
    #         # try predict_proba, then decision_function if it doesn't exist
    #         prediction_method = predict_proba or decision_function
    #     else:
    #         prediction_method = (predict_proba if response_method ==
    #                              'predict_proba' else decision_function)
    #     if prediction_method is None:
    #         if response_method == 'auto':
    #             raise ValueError(
    #                 'The estimator has no predict_proba and no '
    #                 'decision_function method.'
    #             )
    #         elif response_method == 'predict_proba':
    #             raise ValueError('The estimator has no predict_proba method.')
    #         else:
    #             raise ValueError(
    #                 'The estimator has no decision_function method.')
    prediction_method = est.predict

    #the rest in this function are as they were before, beginning with:
    for new_values in grid:
        X_eval = X.copy()

        ....
```

Then comment out the first 20 lines of the definition of `partial_dependence`:

```
def partial_dependence(estimator, X, features, response_method='auto',
                   percentiles=(0.05, 0.95), grid_resolution=100,
                   method='auto'):
    ... (skipping docstring)
    # if not (is_classifier(estimator) or is_regressor(estimator)):
    #     raise ValueError(
    #         "'estimator' must be a fitted regressor or classifier."
    #     )
    # 
    # if isinstance(estimator, Pipeline):
    #     # TODO: to be removed if/when pipeline get a `steps_` attributes
    #     # assuming Pipeline is the only estimator that does not store a new
    #     # attribute
    #     for est in estimator:
    #         # FIXME: remove the None option when it will be deprecated
    #         if est not in (None, 'drop'):
    #             check_is_fitted(est)
    # else:
    #     check_is_fitted(estimator)
    # 
    # if (is_classifier(estimator) and
    #         isinstance(estimator.classes_[0], np.ndarray)):
    #     raise ValueError(
    #         'Multiclass-multioutput estimators are not supported'
    #     )

    #The rest of the function continues as it was:
    # Use check_array only on lists and other non-array-likes / sparse. Do not
    # convert DataFrame into a NumPy array.
    if not(hasattr(X, '__array__') or sparse.issparse(X)):
        X = check_array(X, force_all_finite='allow-nan', dtype=np.object)

        ....
```

If your model is of a different sort or you are using different parameters, you may need to make other changes.

On my model it works exactly as I had hoped. But like I said it's a work-around and it's not the most satisfying solution. Also, your success may vary significantly depending on what type of model or parameters you are trying to use.

Comment: I think since this is now is raised in two very different algos (tf regressor and lgbm classifier) and affects also the latest ver ('0.23.1') you or I could now safely open an issue on Github.

Comment: Any updates on this? I tried the latest sklearn version (0.23.2) and the issue seems to still be there...

Comment: It hasn't worked for me either. The only extra information I have found are on the [github issue #17423](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/17423) but the offered solution is along the same lines...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scikeras](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/), a scikit-learn wrapper for keras model. See the minimal example below. It works for me.

```py
# imports
import numpy as np 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay

# generate random input output
X = np.random.normal(size=(10,2))
y = np.random.normal(size=10)

# define keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(2,)))

# create and fit scikeras object
kr = KerasRegressor(build_fn=model, loss='mse')
kr.fit(X,y, epochs=1)

# use scikeras object on PartialDependenceDisplay
PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(kr, X, features = [0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The "hack" proposed by DrSandwich works like a charm -- I was struggling with the same problem as I was using an ARIMA model which does not follow the traditional sklearn syntax -- I wrote a wrapper and did the adjustments to the .py file that DrSandwich suggested... thank you so much!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
"""Partial dependence plots for regression and classification models."""

# Authors: Peter Prettenhofer
#          Trevor Stephens
#          Nicolas Hug
# License: BSD 3 clause

from collections.abc import Iterable

import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.stats.mstats import mquantiles

from ._pd_utils import _check_feature_names, _get_feature_index
from ..base import is_classifier, is_regressor
from ..utils.extmath import cartesian
from ..utils import check_array
from ..utils import check_matplotlib_support  # noqa
from ..utils import _safe_indexing
from ..utils import _safe_assign
from ..utils import _determine_key_type
from ..utils import _get_column_indices
from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
from ..utils import Bunch
from ..tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from ..ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from ..exceptions import NotFittedError
from ..ensemble._gb import BaseGradientBoosting
from ..ensemble._hist_gradient_boosting.gradient_boosting import (
    BaseHistGradientBoosting,
)


__all__ = [
    "partial_dependence",
]


def _grid_from_X(X, percentiles, is_categorical, grid_resolution):
    """Generate a grid of points based on the percentiles of X.

    The grid is a cartesian product between the columns of ``values``. The
    ith column of ``values`` consists in ``grid_resolution`` equally-spaced
    points between the percentiles of the jth column of X.

    If ``grid_resolution`` is bigger than the number of unique values in the
    j-th column of X or if the feature is a categorical feature (by inspecting
    `is_categorical`) , then those unique values will be used instead.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like of shape (n_samples, n_target_features)
        The data.

    percentiles : tuple of float
        The percentiles which are used to construct the extreme values of
        the grid. Must be in [0, 1].

    is_categorical : list of bool
        For each feature, tells whether it is categorical or not. If a feature
        is categorical, then the values used will be the unique ones
        (i.e. categories) instead of the percentiles.

    grid_resolution : int
        The number of equally spaced points to be placed on the grid for each
        feature.

    Returns
    -------
    grid : ndarray of shape (n_points, n_target_features)
        A value for each feature at each point in the grid. ``n_points`` is
        always ``<= grid_resolution ** X.shape[1]``.

    values : list of 1d ndarrays
        The values with which the grid has been created. The size of each
        array ``values[j]`` is either ``grid_resolution``, or the number of
        unique values in ``X[:, j]``, whichever is smaller.
    """
    if not isinstance(percentiles, Iterable) or len(percentiles) != 2:
        raise ValueError("'percentiles' must be a sequence of 2 elements.")
    if not all(0 <= x <= 1 for x in percentiles):
        raise ValueError("'percentiles' values must be in [0, 1].")
    if percentiles[0] >= percentiles[1]:
        raise ValueError("percentiles[0] must be strictly less than percentiles[1].")

    if grid_resolution <= 1:
        raise ValueError("'grid_resolution' must be strictly greater than 1.")

    values = []
    for feature, is_cat in enumerate(is_categorical):
        uniques = np.unique(_safe_indexing(X, feature, axis=1))
        if is_cat or uniques.shape[0] < grid_resolution:
            # Use the unique values either because:
            # - feature has low resolution use unique values
            # - feature is categorical
            axis = uniques
        else:
            # create axis based on percentiles and grid resolution
            emp_percentiles = mquantiles(
                _safe_indexing(X, feature, axis=1), prob=percentiles, axis=0
            )
            if np.allclose(emp_percentiles[0], emp_percentiles[1]):
                raise ValueError(
                    "percentiles are too close to each other, "
                    "unable to build the grid. Please choose percentiles "
                    "that are further apart."
                )
            axis = np.linspace(
                emp_percentiles[0],
                emp_percentiles[1],
                num=grid_resolution,
                endpoint=True,
            )
        values.append(axis)

    return cartesian(values), values


def _partial_dependence_recursion(est, grid, features):
    averaged_predictions = est._compute_partial_dependence_recursion(grid, features)
    if averaged_predictions.ndim == 1:
        # reshape to (1, n_points) for consistency with
        # _partial_dependence_brute
        averaged_predictions = averaged_predictions.reshape(1, -1)

    return averaged_predictions


def _partial_dependence_brute(est, grid, features, X, response_method):

    predictions = []
    averaged_predictions = []

    # define the prediction_method (predict, predict_proba, decision_function).
    if is_regressor(est):
        prediction_method = est.predict
    else:
        predict_proba = getattr(est, "predict_proba", None)
        decision_function = getattr(est, "decision_function", None)
        if response_method == "auto":
            # try predict_proba, then decision_function if it doesn't exist
            prediction_method = predict_proba or decision_function
        else:
            prediction_method = (
                predict_proba
                if response_method == "predict_proba"
                else decision_function
            )
        if prediction_method is None:
            if response_method == "auto":
                raise ValueError(
                    "The estimator has no predict_proba and no "
                    "decision_function method."
                )
            elif response_method == "predict_proba":
                raise ValueError("The estimator has no predict_proba method.")
            else:
                raise ValueError("The estimator has no decision_function method.")

    X_eval = X.copy()
    for new_values in grid:
        for i, variable in enumerate(features):
            _safe_assign(X_eval, new_values[i], column_indexer=variable)

        try:
            # Note: predictions is of shape
            # (n_points,) for non-multioutput regressors
            # (n_points, n_tasks) for multioutput regressors
            # (n_points, 1) for the regressors in cross_decomposition (I think)
            # (n_points, 2) for binary classification
            # (n_points, n_classes) for multiclass classification
            pred = prediction_method(X_eval)

            predictions.append(pred)
            # average over samples
            averaged_predictions.append(np.mean(pred, axis=0))
        except NotFittedError as e:
            raise ValueError("'estimator' parameter must be a fitted estimator") from e

    n_samples = X.shape[0]

    # reshape to (n_targets, n_instances, n_points) where n_targets is:
    # - 1 for non-multioutput regression and binary classification (shape is
    #   already correct in those cases)
    # - n_tasks for multi-output regression
    # - n_classes for multiclass classification.
    predictions = np.array(predictions).T
    if is_regressor(est) and predictions.ndim == 2:
        # non-multioutput regression, shape is (n_instances, n_points,)
        predictions = predictions.reshape(n_samples, -1)
    elif is_classifier(est) and predictions.shape[0] == 2:
        # Binary classification, shape is (2, n_instances, n_points).
        # we output the effect of **positive** class
        predictions = predictions[1]
        predictions = predictions.reshape(n_samples, -1)

    # reshape averaged_predictions to (n_targets, n_points) where n_targets is:
    # - 1 for non-multioutput regression and binary classification (shape is
    #   already correct in those cases)
    # - n_tasks for multi-output regression
    # - n_classes for multiclass classification.
    averaged_predictions = np.array(averaged_predictions).T
    if is_regressor(est) and averaged_predictions.ndim == 1:
        # non-multioutput regression, shape is (n_points,)
        averaged_predictions = averaged_predictions.reshape(1, -1)
    elif is_classifier(est) and averaged_predictions.shape[0] == 2:
        # Binary classification, shape is (2, n_points).
        # we output the effect of **positive** class
        averaged_predictions = averaged_predictions[1]
        averaged_predictions = averaged_predictions.reshape(1, -1)

    return averaged_predictions, predictions


def partial_dependence(
    estimator,
    X,
    features,
    *,
    categorical_features=None,
    feature_names=None,
    response_method="auto",
    percentiles=(0.05, 0.95),
    grid_resolution=100,
    method="auto",
    kind="average",
):
    """Partial dependence of ``features``.

    Partial dependence of a feature (or a set of features) corresponds to
    the average response of an estimator for each possible value of the
    feature.

    Read more in the :ref:`User Guide <partial_dependence>`.

    .. warning::

        For :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier` and
        :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor`, the
        `'recursion'` method (used by default) will not account for the `init`
        predictor of the boosting process. In practice, this will produce
        the same values as `'brute'` up to a constant offset in the target
        response, provided that `init` is a constant estimator (which is the
        default). However, if `init` is not a constant estimator, the
        partial dependence values are incorrect for `'recursion'` because the
        offset will be sample-dependent. It is preferable to use the `'brute'`
        method. Note that this only applies to
        :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier` and
        :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor`, not to
        :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier` and
        :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingRegressor`.

    Parameters
    ----------
    estimator : BaseEstimator
        A fitted estimator object implementing :term:`predict`,
        :term:`predict_proba`, or :term:`decision_function`.
        Multioutput-multiclass classifiers are not supported.

    X : {array-like or dataframe} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
        ``X`` is used to generate a grid of values for the target
        ``features`` (where the partial dependence will be evaluated), and
        also to generate values for the complement features when the
        `method` is 'brute'.

    features : array-like of {int, str}
        The feature (e.g. `[0]`) or pair of interacting features
        (e.g. `[(0, 1)]`) for which the partial dependency should be computed.

    categorical_features : array-like of shape (n_features,) or shape \
            (n_categorical_features,), dtype={bool, int, str}, default=None
        Indicates the categorical features.

        - `None`: no feature will be considered categorical;
        - boolean array-like: boolean mask of shape `(n_features,)`
            indicating which features are categorical. Thus, this array has
            the same shape has `X.shape[1]`;
        - integer or string array-like: integer indices or strings
            indicating categorical features.

        .. versionadded:: 1.2

    feature_names : array-like of shape (n_features,), dtype=str, default=None
        Name of each feature; `feature_names[i]` holds the name of the feature
        with index `i`.
        By default, the name of the feature corresponds to their numerical
        index for NumPy array and their column name for pandas dataframe.

        .. versionadded:: 1.2

    response_method : {'auto', 'predict_proba', 'decision_function'}, \
            default='auto'
        Specifies whether to use :term:`predict_proba` or
        :term:`decision_function` as the target response. For regressors
        this parameter is ignored and the response is always the output of
        :term:`predict`. By default, :term:`predict_proba` is tried first
        and we revert to :term:`decision_function` if it doesn't exist. If
        ``method`` is 'recursion', the response is always the output of
        :term:`decision_function`.

    percentiles : tuple of float, default=(0.05, 0.95)
        The lower and upper percentile used to create the extreme values
        for the grid. Must be in [0, 1].

    grid_resolution : int, default=100
        The number of equally spaced points on the grid, for each target
        feature.

    method : {'auto', 'recursion', 'brute'}, default='auto'
        The method used to calculate the averaged predictions:

        - `'recursion'` is only supported for some tree-based estimators
          (namely
          :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier`,
          :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor`,
          :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier`,
          :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingRegressor`,
          :class:`~sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor`,
          :class:`~sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor`,
          ) when `kind='average'`.
          This is more efficient in terms of speed.
          With this method, the target response of a
          classifier is always the decision function, not the predicted
          probabilities. Since the `'recursion'` method implicitly computes
          the average of the Individual Conditional Expectation (ICE) by
          design, it is not compatible with ICE and thus `kind` must be
          `'average'`.

        - `'brute'` is supported for any estimator, but is more
          computationally intensive.

        - `'auto'`: the `'recursion'` is used for estimators that support it,
          and `'brute'` is used otherwise.

        Please see :ref:`this note <pdp_method_differences>` for
        differences between the `'brute'` and `'recursion'` method.

    kind : {'average', 'individual', 'both'}, default='average'
        Whether to return the partial dependence averaged across all the
        samples in the dataset or one value per sample or both.
        See Returns below.

        Note that the fast `method='recursion'` option is only available for
        `kind='average'`. Computing individual dependencies requires using the
        slower `method='brute'` option.

        .. versionadded:: 0.24

    Returns
    -------
    predictions : :class:`~sklearn.utils.Bunch`
        Dictionary-like object, with the following attributes.

        individual : ndarray of shape (n_outputs, n_instances, \
                len(values[0]), len(values[1]), ...)
            The predictions for all the points in the grid for all
            samples in X. This is also known as Individual
            Conditional Expectation (ICE)

        average : ndarray of shape (n_outputs, len(values[0]), \
                len(values[1]), ...)
            The predictions for all the points in the grid, averaged
            over all samples in X (or over the training data if
            ``method`` is 'recursion').
            Only available when ``kind='both'``.

        values : seq of 1d ndarrays
            The values with which the grid has been created. The generated
            grid is a cartesian product of the arrays in ``values``.
            ``len(values) == len(features)``. The size of each array
            ``values[j]`` is either ``grid_resolution``, or the number of
            unique values in ``X[:, j]``, whichever is smaller.

        ``n_outputs`` corresponds to the number of classes in a multi-class
        setting, or to the number of tasks for multi-output regression.
        For classical regression and binary classification ``n_outputs==1``.
        ``n_values_feature_j`` corresponds to the size ``values[j]``.

    See Also
    --------
    PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator : Plot Partial Dependence.
    PartialDependenceDisplay : Partial Dependence visualization.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> X = [[0, 0, 2], [1, 0, 0]]
    >>> y = [0, 1]
    >>> from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
    >>> gb = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X, y)
    >>> partial_dependence(gb, features=[0], X=X, percentiles=(0, 1),
    ...                    grid_resolution=2) # doctest: +SKIP
    (array([[-4.52...,  4.52...]]), [array([ 0.,  1.])])
    """
    check_is_fitted(estimator)

    if not (is_classifier(estimator) or is_regressor(estimator)):
        raise ValueError("'estimator' must be a fitted regressor or classifier.")

    if is_classifier(estimator) and isinstance(estimator.classes_[0], np.ndarray):
        raise ValueError("Multiclass-multioutput estimators are not supported")

    # Use check_array only on lists and other non-array-likes / sparse. Do not
    # convert DataFrame into a NumPy array.
    if not (hasattr(X, "__array__") or sparse.issparse(X)):
        X = check_array(X, force_all_finite="allow-nan", dtype=object)

    accepted_responses = ("auto", "predict_proba", "decision_function")
    if response_method not in accepted_responses:
        raise ValueError(
            "response_method {} is invalid. Accepted response_method names "
            "are {}.".format(response_method, ", ".join(accepted_responses))
        )

    if is_regressor(estimator) and response_method != "auto":
        raise ValueError(
            "The response_method parameter is ignored for regressors and "
            "must be 'auto'."
        )

    accepted_methods = ("brute", "recursion", "auto")
    if method not in accepted_methods:
        raise ValueError(
            "method {} is invalid. Accepted method names are {}.".format(
                method, ", ".join(accepted_methods)
            )
        )

    if kind != "average":
        if method == "recursion":
            raise ValueError(
                "The 'recursion' method only applies when 'kind' is set to 'average'"
            )
        method = "brute"

    if method == "auto":
        if isinstance(estimator, BaseGradientBoosting) and estimator.init is None:
            method = "recursion"
        elif isinstance(
            estimator,
            (BaseHistGradientBoosting, DecisionTreeRegressor, RandomForestRegressor),
        ):
            method = "recursion"
        else:
            method = "brute"

    if method == "recursion":
        if not isinstance(
            estimator,
            (
                BaseGradientBoosting,
                BaseHistGradientBoosting,
                DecisionTreeRegressor,
                RandomForestRegressor,
            ),
        ):
            supported_classes_recursion = (
                "GradientBoostingClassifier",
                "GradientBoostingRegressor",
                "HistGradientBoostingClassifier",
                "HistGradientBoostingRegressor",
                "HistGradientBoostingRegressor",
                "DecisionTreeRegressor",
                "RandomForestRegressor",
            )
            raise ValueError(
                "Only the following estimators support the 'recursion' "
                "method: {}. Try using method='brute'.".format(
                    ", ".join(supported_classes_recursion)
                )
            )
        if response_method == "auto":
            response_method = "decision_function"

        if response_method != "decision_function":
            raise ValueError(
                "With the 'recursion' method, the response_method must be "
                "'decision_function'. Got {}.".format(response_method)
            )

    if _determine_key_type(features, accept_slice=False) == "int":
        # _get_column_indices() supports negative indexing. Here, we limit
        # the indexing to be positive. The upper bound will be checked
        # by _get_column_indices()
        if np.any(np.less(features, 0)):
            raise ValueError("all features must be in [0, {}]".format(X.shape[1] - 1))

    features_indices = np.asarray(
        _get_column_indices(X, features), dtype=np.int32, order="C"
    ).ravel()

    feature_names = _check_feature_names(X, feature_names)

    n_features = X.shape[1]
    if categorical_features is None:
        is_categorical = [False] * len(features_indices)
    else:
        categorical_features = np.array(categorical_features, copy=False)
        if categorical_features.dtype.kind == "b":
            # categorical features provided as a list of boolean
            if categorical_features.size != n_features:
                raise ValueError(
                    "When `categorical_features` is a boolean array-like, "
                    "the array should be of shape (n_features,). Got "
                    f"{categorical_features.size} elements while `X` contains "
                    f"{n_features} features."
                )
            is_categorical = [categorical_features[idx] for idx in features_indices]
        elif categorical_features.dtype.kind in ("i", "O", "U"):
            # categorical features provided as a list of indices or feature names
            categorical_features_idx = [
                _get_feature_index(cat, feature_names=feature_names)
                for cat in categorical_features
            ]
            is_categorical = [
                idx in categorical_features_idx for idx in features_indices
            ]
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                "Expected `categorical_features` to be an array-like of boolean,"
                f" integer, or string. Got {categorical_features.dtype} instead."
            )

    grid, values = _grid_from_X(
        _safe_indexing(X, features_indices, axis=1),
        percentiles,
        is_categorical,
        grid_resolution,
    )

    if method == "brute":
        averaged_predictions, predictions = _partial_dependence_brute(
            estimator, grid, features_indices, X, response_method
        )

        # reshape predictions to
        # (n_outputs, n_instances, n_values_feature_0, n_values_feature_1, ...)
        predictions = predictions.reshape(
            -1, X.shape[0], *[val.shape[0] for val in values]
        )
    else:
        averaged_predictions = _partial_dependence_recursion(
            estimator, grid, features_indices
        )

    # reshape averaged_predictions to
    # (n_outputs, n_values_feature_0, n_values_feature_1, ...)
    averaged_predictions = averaged_predictions.reshape(
        -1, *[val.shape[0] for val in values]
    )

    if kind == "average":
        return Bunch(average=averaged_predictions, values=values)
    elif kind == "individual":
        return Bunch(individual=predictions, values=values)
    else:  # kind='both'
        return Bunch(
            average=averaged_predictions,
            individual=predictions,
            values=values,
        )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).